# Find all elements with onclick attribute using selenium?

Tags: python, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to `find_elements` using `xpath` and an `attribute` that is `onclick`.

Example element:

```
< a
    href = "#"
    onclick = "javascript:ValidateLink(&quot;FNOSquareOffBuySell&quot;,&quot;NATMIN,NFO,8503107736,S,6000,0,30-Aug-2018,E,11500,C,O,S,E,*,35,0,0,0,0,0,,,0,118.85,0,,,*,*,,NVTC&quot;)" >
    Square & nbsp;
    Off < / a >
```

It would be a bonus if I can filter it further while using the find command by the `Square & nbsp;
        Off`

I have tried:

```
ch = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*contains(@onclick,\"FNOSquareOffBuySell&quot\")]")

ch = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@onclick)]")
```

I want to find the elements, then get the onclick attribute text and use it to decide which element to click.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `//*[@onclick]` for looking all of the onclick elements?

also, you made a type for `"//*contains(@onclick,\"FNOSquareOffBuySell&quot\")]"`, 
did you mean 
`//*[contains(@onclick,\"FNOSquareOffBuySell&quot\")]`

OR

`//*contains(@onclick,'FNOSquareOffBuySell&quot')]`